# How to fix "Page not found(404)" error in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to build a restaurant site for learning Django. The site is very much simple but I am trying to make the site little dynamic. For eg: When users clicks Lunch, the url changes to **"http://127.0.0.1:8000/menu/Lunch/"** and lunch menu is displayed and so on (of course I am making a single template file to handle this). I have done the following implementation and I am getting **"Page not Found(404)"** error. Help me out please.

My urls.py looks like this:

```
 urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name="index"),
  path('menu/', views.menu, name="menu"),
  path('menu/<str:menu_category>/', views.menu_detail, name="menu_detail"),
 ]
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
def menu_detail(request, menu_category):
 menu_list = get_list_or_404(Menu, category=menu_category)
 menu_title = Menu.objects.get(category=menu_category)
 return render(request, 'restaurant/menu_detail.html', {'menu_list': 
 menu_list, 'menu_title': menu_title})
```

Also, I have made menu_detail.html file under "restaurant/templates" and I have correct path set in settings.py.

EDIT :

My Models look like this:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User,default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 name = models.CharField("Name of the dish",max_length=30)
 category = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,default='SP')
 description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
 dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

Comment: What does your `Menu` model look like?

Comment: Hey @DanielHepper I have made edit on the post.

Comment: I think I found where the error is. My CATEGORY_CHOICES have Abbreviated name for all the menu categories and in Views, I am trying to query my database with Full name of the menu category. That's where no matching query is found because of which 404 error is occuring.